# Cannot get a reference to a dijit form when the form has a DateTextBox

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I am having trouble getting a reference to the dijit form widget when the form contains a DateTextBox.  The code snippet below demonstrates the problem.  When executed, the alert box says "undefined".  However, if I get rid of `<input ... id="dateTextBox"... />`, I am able to get a reference to the form widget.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">

        <!-- load dojo and provide config via data attribute -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: true">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require(["dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/DateTextBox"]);
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/registry", "dijit/form/Form", "dojo/domReady!"],
            function(parser, registry) {
                parser.parse();
                alert(registry.byId("frm_test"));
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body class="claro">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="frm_test" encType="multipart/form-data" action="" method="">  
            <input type="text" id="textBox" name="textBox" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" />
            <input type="text" id="dateTextBox" name="dateTextBox" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are parsing twice.  If you set `parseOnLoad: false`, does the problem still occur?

Comment: Yes, the problem is still there if I set parseOnLoad to false.  For some reason, registry.byId does not work here unless I do a manual parse, but that's a different question.

Comment: I don't know if my answer will solve your problem, but I offer it as a suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend wrapping the `registry.byId` into a `ready` call.

Keep `parse onLoad: true`, remove

```
require(["dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/DateTextBox"]);
```

as the parser will auto require (when dojo>= 1.8) and use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/registry", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(ready, registry) {
            // by default the prioirty of this ready call will be after the 
            // ready call used to parse when parseOnLoad is true
            ready(function() { 
                alert(registry.byId("frm_test"));
            });
    });
</script>
```

> Note that waiting for dojo/domReady! to fire is often not sufficient
>   when working with widgets. Many widgets shouldn’t be initialized or
>   accessed until the following modules load and execute:
>
> - dojo/uacss
> - dijit/hccss
> - dojo/parser
>
> Thus when working with widgets you should generally put your code
>   inside of a dojo/ready() callback

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/domReady.html

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/ready.html#dojo-ready

Comment: Your suggestion to wrap registry.byId in a ready callback worked.  Now that I understand what the problem is, I'd like to post an excerpt from dojo documentation for the benefit of others that might have the same problem:

Comment: "Note that waiting for dojo/domReady! to fire is often not sufficient when working with widgets. Many widgets shouldn’t be initialized or accessed until the following modules load and execute:
    dojo/uacss
    dijit/hccss
    dojo/parser
Thus when working with widgets you should generally put your code inside of a dojo/ready() callback"

Comment: Thank you for your other suggestions as well.  I did not realize that manually requiring modules was no longer necessary.  It appears that "dojo/parser" still needs to be manually required when `parseOnLoad` is set to `true`.