# Dojo Errors Post-AMD Conversion

Tags: javascript, dojo

Having made a bunch of general javascripts AMD compatible, i'm running into some errors which are blocking progress:

- TypeError: registry.byId(...) is undefined
- TypeError: _3ff is null (also _3f9)

Tracing the error "registry.byId()" leads to domConstruct.place(...), and errors like "_3ff is null" seems to point to the line "domConstruct.place(content, dom.byId($parent));" suggesting that the Id required isn't available.... although the modules are all including "dojo/domReady!".

'dojo/dom-construct' is a listed dependency of the module, and domConstruct variable has been created.

As an example, one of the starting points for this kind of error is a `<td>`:

```
content += '<td valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" id="somethingBlahMessages">';
// calls a function in another module where a <div> is created and filled
// see below
setTimeout(require('js/somethingMessages').somethingMessagesInit(), 1);
content += '</td>';

// function from another module to create div and fill with data 
var content = '';
content += '<div id="somethingMessages"></div>';

domConstruct.place(content, dom.byId('somethingBlahMessages'));     
// fetch the data, functions down the line also use domConstruct.place/empty
somethingMessagesTimer = setTimeout(that.somethingMessagesGet(), 1);
```

The content which ought to be added to the td#somethingBlahMessages isn't getting there. Is this a parsing issue?

This all used to work fine the non-AMD way, so i'm also suspicious that it's a red-herring, and the real error is cunningly disguised under branches and twigs and i've walked right past it....

**EDIT:** I tried converting only one of my scripts into an AMD module, and in doing so it fails with a "_3f9 is null" TypeError immediately when it encounters a domConstruct.place (the stack trace ends at the place function).

Comment: Use the SDK/development/full source version of Dojo when you are developing. The prebuilt release versions are not useful for debugging, with no lines and minified identifiers like `_3f9`. Also, if you are converting modules, you really should actually provide the AMD module part of your AMD module in your question :)

Comment: Thanks, C, for the heads up regarding using the uncompressed version of Dojo!  Errors are indeed more informative now....For the record, these errors seem to have been resolved by wrapping dom.byId in a ready callback (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18411608/5819371 for a fuller explanation).